# Excel VBA Form Control - Reset Listbox Scroll Bar

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, scroll, position

I have written the below code to pull the data from six listboxes (multiselect) on the same sheet, pass the selections to a module for calculation and then clear the listbox selections. The only issue which seems negligible although very frustrating is getting the listbox 'scroll bar' for each listbox to reset its position to the top of the list.

I have tried .TopIndex but because i am using a form control and not an ActiveX control it returns "object" not supported.

Does anyone know how to reset the listbox scroll bar position to the top of the form control listbox?

```
Sub Listboxproperties_click()

    'store selected items from listbox into an array
    Dim listarray()
    Dim J As Integer
    Dim R As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    'Add selected items into the array
    ReDim listarray(1 To 50, 1 To 6)
    'Counter
    J = 0
    For R = 1 To 6
        Set lb = ActiveSheet.ListBoxes("ListBox" & R)
        For i = 1 To lb.ListCount
            If lb.Selected(i) = True Then
                'add 1 to the counter
                J = J + 1
                'Store selection in an array
                listarray(J, R) = lb.list(i)
            End If
        Next i
        J = 0
    Next R

    'Check if msgbox has a selection if not exit sub
    For R = 1 To 6
        'if there is nothing in the first item of the listarray then the user has not chosen an option
        If listarray(1, R) = "" Then
            MsgBox "You have not selected a option, please select and retry"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next R

    'input box for the name of the Trend

    Linename = InputBox("Please enter a name for the call type you are calculating i.e. Adviser Calls, Withdrawal   Status etc", "Call Trend")

    If Linename = "" Then
        MsgBox "No name selected, please retry and enter a name for your call flow"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Call UniqueCount(listarray, Linename)

    'clear selections from listbox
    For R = 1 To 6
        Set lb = ActiveSheet.ListBoxes("ListBox" & R)
        For i = 1 To lb.ListCount - 1
            If lb.Selected(i) = True Then
                lb.Selected = False
            End If
        Next i
        lb.TopIndex
    Next R

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I found it's to clean and reinsert values...

```
Dim xx(1 To 10000) As String
Set o = ActiveSheet.Shapes("List Box 1")
e = 1
For e = 1 To o.ControlFormat.ListCount
    xx(e) = o.ControlFormat.List(e)
Next
o.ControlFormat.RemoveAllItems
For i = 1 To e
    o.ControlFormat.AddItem xx(i)
Next
o.ControlFormat.ListIndex = 1
```

because the **ListIndex** select the first element, but not active and you cannot use the Keyboard to move inside ...

Answer (score 0):

I am not expert enough to write a code to help you but I have a thought thay may work which you could either attempt to code or someone else smarter than us could help out with.

You say you are using multi select so when resetting, could you potentially do the following?:

1. Remove all selections
2. Turn off Multi Select to Single Select
3. Select the first item in the listbox (i.e. bring the focus to the top)
4. Remove this selection
5. Return this listbox to Multi Select

The reason I'm thinking to try Single Select is because with Multi Select the listbox ok with selecting without focusing on the selected item.  This is more a theory but seeing as no one has attempted an answer I thought I'd try to help.  Can anyone confirm or deny my idea?